# if statements with char values

Tags: c++, if-statement, char

So I'm trying to write an easy basic game here with basic C++, and when I try to execute this

```
// global variabless
const char UP = 'w', LEFT = 'a', DOWN = 's', RIGHT = 'd'; // player movement choices
char playerMove; // goes with askPlayer

void askPlayer()
{
    char choice;
    cout << "Use the WASD keys to move: ";
    cin >> choice;
    int worked;

    do{
        if (choice == 'w' || choice == 'W')
        {
            playerMove = UP;
            worked = 1;
        }
        else if (choice == 'a' || choice == 'A')
        {
            playerMove = LEFT;
            worked = 1;
        }
        else if (playerMove == 's' || playerMove == 'S')
        {
            playerMove = DOWN;
            worked = 1;
        }
        else if (playerMove == 'd' || playerMove == 'D')
        {
            playerMove = RIGHT;
            worked = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid entry." << endl;
            worked = 0;
        }
    } while (worked != 1);
    return;
}
```

It works up to the user entering a letter. Xcode says (lldb) then the page fills up with numbers, and after you stop the run, it says "Program ended with exit code: 9". It does this even if you enter one of the valid values

Comment: Ever heard of `switch`? Also, you seem to be inconsistent in your use of `choice` and `playerMove`. Correcting that, if you enter the loop with a `playerMove` (or `choice`) which does not "work", how do you expect to ever make progress?

Comment: Please use `std::tolower`, in `<cctype>`, to convert your letter to lower case before comparing.  Eliminates a lot of typing.

Comment: Please use `bool` variables for `true/false` conditions rather than 1 or zero.  Times have changed since the 1960's.

Comment: You don't need to assign `playerMove` because it's redundant. For example, `RIGHT == 'd'` and substituting, the assignment becomes `playerMove = 'd';` and `playerMove` already equals 'd', by logic of the `if` statement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: `tolower()` is a bit tricky. Its argument is an `int` that has to be within the range of `unsigned char` (or it can be `EOF`, which is typically `-1`). If plain `char` is signed, and you happen to have a `char` value with the sign bit set, then calling `std::tolower()` has undefined behavior. Use `std::tolower((unsigned char)c)` (or whichever flavor of C++-style cast is more appropriate).

Answer (score 3):

You never prompt for another value after the user enters the first one:

```
cin >> choice; // <==
int worked;

do {
    // ..
} while (worked != 1);
```

Just move the input into the loop:

```
int worked;
do {
    cin >> choice; // possibly with cout prompt too
    // rest as before
} while (worked != 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input is outside the loop, your variable `worked`  is uninitialized ( though it is not a error in your code but is cleaner to initialize your variables) and it should have `bool` type.  Whole code can be simplified by the `switch` statement:

```
void askPlayer()
{
    do {
        char choice;
        cout << "Use the WASD keys to move: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch( choice ) {
            case 'w' : case 'W' :
                playerMove = UP;
                break;
            case 'a' : case 'A' :
                playerMove = LEFT;
                break;
            case 's' : case 'S' :
                playerMove = DOWN;
                break;
            case 'd' : case 'D' :
                playerMove = RIGHT;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid entry." << endl;
                continue;
        }
    } while( false );
    return;
}
```